# SelectDateWidget Not Working

Tags: django, django-forms

In the following code I'm trying to use the SelectDateWidget for date inputs, however it isn't being applied to hire_date as expected. I've set the widget up just like I've seen others do it, but for some reason it continues to just display the default text-based datefield input. Thanks in advance for the help!

## Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateInput, DateField, extras
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    hire_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    hire_date = models.DateField()
```

## Template (create.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load sekizai_tags formset_tags %}
{% block base_content %}

{{ formset.media }}

<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="strongborder">
        <div id="main" class="container boldtext">
            <form id="myForm" method="post" class="12u">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="2u">
                            {{ field.label_tag }}:
                        </div>
                        <div class="10u">
                            {{ field }}
                            {{ field.errors }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            <div class="row 12u">
                <input type="submit" value="Save New Employee">    
            </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does replacing `widget=extras.SelectDateWidget` with `widget=extras.SelectDateWidget()` change anything?

Comment: @alecxe Making that change did not do anything. Do I need to be handling hire_date specially through my template? Or should it work fine when called through {{ field }}?

Answer (score 0):

from django import forms
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

If you are using django 1.7 Try this :

hire_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())

You can find the reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget.months)

Comment: I'm using version 1.5, which still contains the SelectDateWidget. I tried the "hire_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())" formatting and hire_date still shows as a text field.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not modify the field but change a widget. It works for me on 1.6.

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        widgets = {'hire_date': SelectDateWidget()}}
```

Please note that an instance should be passed rather than a class.